# How to configure Pusher Beams SDK with Firebase in App Delegate?

Tags: ios, firebase, push-notification, appdelegate, pusher

I have the Firebase SDK in my project for the backend and I am using the Beams SDK from Pusher to configure push notifications.

The issue is that, it doesn't seem that my app delegate is configuring the settings I need to send notification with the Beams SDK if I have Firebase. Here is what I mean.

According to the Beams SDK I need to place this code in the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
    
    self.pushNotifications.start(instanceId: "MyInstanceID")
        self.pushNotifications.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        try? self.pushNotifications.addDeviceInterest(interest: "debug-hello")
   // FirebaseApp.configure() . However it ONLY works properly when this is commented out
    
    
    
    return true
}
```

As I showed above, it only configures my notifications properly if I comment out the Firebase configuration. Here is other relevant code in my delegate:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
        
        print("RECEIVED NOTIFICATION")
        self.pushNotifications.handleNotification(userInfo: userInfo)
   
       
        
        if Auth.auth().canHandleNotification(userInfo){
            completionHandler(.noData)
            return
        }
        
        
    }


func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        print("Did register for remote notifications")
        self.pushNotifications.registerDeviceToken(deviceToken)
        Auth.auth().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: .prod)
        

    }
```

How do I properly configure both in my project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that `Firebase.configure()` will break the `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` method.

You need to add `GoogleUtilitiesAppDelegateProxyEnabled` to the `info.plist` and set it to `NO`.